# Pydiction <Tab> isnot popping up with code completion suggestions

Tags: python, vim

I installed Pathogen
and followed http://rkulla.github.io/pydiction/ for installing pydiction

Configuration in my /root/.vimrc also I changed in the path which is given by `:echo $MYVIMRC`

My .vimrc file :-

```
filetype plugin on
let g:pydiction_location = '/root/.vim/bundle/pydiction/complete-dict'
let g:pydiction_menu_height = 3
```

But after these all instructions also I am not getting any suggessions ( by giving tab key) from complete-dict

If anything I left to configure please help me

when I am pressing `C-N` also in my vim file it is showing like this :-

> -- Keyword completion (^N^P) Pattern not found

Comment: Are you using Vim as root or a a normal user?

Comment: I am using vim as a root user